# How to combine between Omnet ++ vectors and Pcap file

Tags: dataset, omnet++, veins, inet

Greeting all,

I am simulating Vanet and generate Pcap file moreover the Omnet++ provide a result file which includes vectors...

I need to generate a dataset that contains the source IP address, port# and destination IP address, port#, and other vector statistics.

How can I combine between Omnet++ vectors and Pcap file? or is there an alternative way to add Pcap information in Omnet++ vectors?

Any help will be very appreciated